# Integrating Go and Bazel tests

Tags: go, bazel

In my CI system, I have various go scripts that I run to analyze my Go code. For example, I have a script that validates if various main files can start a long running app successfully. For this I run the go script via `go run startupvalidator -pkgs=pkg1,pkg2,pk3`. I am interested in using Bazel to be able to utilize the cache for this since if `pkg1` has not changed `startupvalidator` would be able to hit the cache for `pkg1` and then run a fresh run for `pkg2` and `pkg3`.

I thought about a couple different ways to do this but none of them feel correct. Is there a "best" way to accomplish this? Is this a reasonable use case for bazel?

I thought about creating a bash script where I run something like:

```
go run startupvalidator $1
```

With a `BUILD.bazel` file containing

```
sh_binary(
  name = "startupvalidator-sh",
  sources = [":startupvalidator.sh"],
  deps = [
    "//go/path/to/startupvalidator",
  ],
)
```

I also thought about placing a similar sh_test in the `BUILD.bazel` file for each `pkg1`, `pkg2`, and `pkg3` so that I could run `bazel run //go/pkg1:startupvalidator`.

However, this doesn't actually work. Does anyone have feedback on how I should go about this? Any directions or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To take advantage of the caching for test results, you need a `*_test` which you run with `bazel test`. Maybe the only part you're missing is that `bazel run` simply runs a binary (even if it's a test binary), while `bazel test` is looking for an up-to-date test result which means it use the cache?

You also need to split up the binary so changing the code in `pkg2` doesn't affect the test action in `pkg1`. The action's key in the cache includes the contents of all its input files, the command being run, etc. I'm not sure if your `startupvalidator` has the various main functions compiled into it, or if it looks for the binaries at runtime. If it compiles them in, you'll need to build separate ones. If it's loading the files at runtime, put the files it looks for in `data` for your test rule so they're part of the inputs to the test action.

I'd do something like this in `pkg1` (assuming it's loading files at runtime; if they're compiled in then you can just make separate `go_test` targets):

```py
sh_test(
  name = 'startupvalidator_test',
  srcs = ['startupvalidator_test.sh'],
  deps = ['@bazel_tools//tools/bash/runfiles'],
  data = ['//go/path/to/startupvalidator', ':package_main'],
)
```

with a `startupvalidator_test.sh` which looks like:

```sh
# --- begin runfiles.bash initialization v2 ---
# Copy-pasted from the Bazel Bash runfiles library v2.
set -uo pipefail; f=bazel_tools/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash
source "${RUNFILES_DIR:-/dev/null}/$f" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "${RUNFILES_MANIFEST_FILE:-/dev/null}" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$0.runfiles/$f" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "$0.runfiles_manifest" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  source "$(grep -sm1 "^$f " "$0.exe.runfiles_manifest" | cut -f2- -d' ')" 2>/dev/null || \
  { echo>&2 "ERROR: cannot find $f"; exit 1; }; f=; set -e

exec $(rlocation workspace/go/path/to/startupvalidator) \
  -main=$(rlocation workspace/pkg1/package_main)
# --- end runfiles.bash initialization v2 ---
```

I'm assuming that `package_main` is the thing loaded by `startupvalidator`. Bazel is set up to pass full paths to dependencies like that to other binaries, so I'm pretending that there's a new flag that takes the full path instead of just the package name. The shell script uses [runfiles.bash](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/bash/runfiles/runfiles.bash) to locate the various files.

If you want to deduplicate this between the packages, I would write a [macro](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html) that uses a [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule) to generate the shell script.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! I just wanted to say that your answer was really helpful in pointing me in the correct direction